# Writing a raw data file in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, hex

I have a number in Mathematica, a large number.  I have even gotten this number in base 16 form, using `OutputForm[]`.  I am basically trying to write out a number to a file in hex format.

Please keep in mind I am using 123456 in these examples instead of my 70,000 digit number.

Whenever I write a file using a simple `Put[123456, "file.raw"]` command, I get a raw data file with the actual data `3132333435360A` with a line ending.

If I use `Put[OutputForm[BaseForm[123456, 16]], "file.raw"]` command, I get a raw data file with the data in hex format `31653234300A202020202031360A` but still not written as raw data.

I would like the Hex Form of the Number Dumped as Data.

I have tried `Export`, `BinaryWrite`, and `DumpSave`, but can't figure it out.

I just am getting a headache I guess cause I can't see past what I need to do.

One thing I did try was doing:

```
Export["file.raw", 123456];
```

But the file is not raw enough.  What I mean by that is there is there is header data and extra crap.

Would love to get this working thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what writing a number out `in hex format` means.  Do you want to create a text file containing the characters in the hex representation of the number you are trying to export, or a binary file in which each group of 4 bits represents one of the hexadecimal digits in your number ?

Comment: @rezwits, can you define exactly what you require as the contents of your "raw" output file. For instance, do you want a sequence of bytes, each one representing a hex character? As in - '1A5' would give a file containing binary 00000001 00001010 00000101.

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing *hexadecimal representation* with *binary data*.  You probably need `BinaryWrite`.  There are other subtleties though such as endianness, the exact binary representation (do you work with reals or integers?  what's the maximum number you need to work with?)

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know what you expect to see in your output file, and what you want use it for.  Do you want something a human can read, or something in a specified format to be used by a computer?  Please provide an example.

The two examples using `Put[]` correctly provide files containing ASCII characters corresponding to the text representations of your inputs, and which are human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is IntegerString[_,16]:

```
In[33]:= IntegerString[123456, 16]

Out[33]= "1e240"

str = OpenWrite[];
WriteString[str, IntegerString[123456, 16]];
Close[str];

FilePrint[%]

1e240
```

(using WriteString instead of Put avoids having the string characters